# Fraud account that money was put into

Tags: fraud

My bank account was fraudulent taken over. They put my money into a bitcoin account it supposed to be the amount of $18500. They have all the information but is supposes to be under my name. They want me to pay them to get it out. I don’t know who why are or what state they are in. I’m just trying to get my money out. I don’t know anything about bitcoin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91943/how-do-i-recover-from-a-cryptocurrency-scam)

Comment: See also [who really controls bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99902/13866)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103891/is-it-normal-to-be-asked-for-an-advance-fee-on-a-withdrawal)

Comment: I feel you should be contacting your bank's fraud dept.

Comment: Your bank covers bank fraud. Do what @Michael Tidwell said.